# Spectrum color picker get the value of the color

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, color-picker

I implemented Spectrum's color picker just fine

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#font_color").spectrum({
    color: "#f00"
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/bgrins/spectrum/master/spectrum.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/bgrins/spectrum/master/spectrum.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<input type="text" id="font_color" />
```

But I don't know how to get the value inside the texfield using javascript. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

the value of the input?

```
var value = $("#font_color").val();
```

Comment: Thank you! I know now to get the value. :) Added onchange to the input

Comment: Doesnt work . $("#font_color").spectrum('get').toHexString(); works though

Answer (score 25):

Another way to also get it, if the input field method does not work for you, is directly from spectrum itself.

```
$("#font_color").spectrum('get');
```

or

```
$("#font_color").spectrum('get').toHexString();
```

To get it converted.

Comment: Why is this so ugly? Is this some kind of jQuery convention? Why is it not:

`var myColorPicker = $('#font_color').spectrum();
var color = myColorPicker.get()`

Answer (score 2):

Use color.toRgbString() work for me